# Undefined is not an object in React native when rendering

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React and React native and am trying to retrieve data from an API and then render it but I seem to be running into problems.

I'm getting errors like:
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'attractions.map') in RenderPhotos_render

I may have jumped into React Native too early...So excuse my lack of knowledge!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    attractions: state.attractions.attractions,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
    GET_Attractions(callback) {
      dispatch({type: 'attractions/GET_Attractions', callback});
    },
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(
  class Home extends Component {
    state = {
      loading: true,
    };

    componentDidMount = () => {
      const callback = () => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
        });
      };

      this.props.GET_Attractions(callback);
    };

    renderMapMarker = () => {
      const {attractions} = this.props;

      return attractions.map(marker => {
        return (
          <Marker
            key={marker.caseId}
            title={marker.caseName}
            description="點擊查看詳細資料"
            coordinate={{
              latitude: marker.latitude,
              longitude: marker.longitude,
            }}
          />
        );
      });
    };

    render() {
      if (this.state.loading) {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <ActivityIndicator />
          </View>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
              style={styles.mapView}
              initialRegion={{
                latitude: 24.149706,
                longitude: 120.683813,
                latitudeDelta: 8,
                longitudeDelta: 8,
              }}>
              {this.renderMapMarker()}
            </MapView>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
  },
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  mapView: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `attractions` might be undefined so you can check to validate first then render if it has data to render like

```
render() {

  if (this.state.loading) {
    return (
     ...
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          ...
          >
          {this.props.attractions && this.renderMapMarker()} // and this
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: erro : Can't find variable:attractions

Comment: @KWJwilliam Try updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a prop "attractions" that is being populated from the reducer, so initially when your screen is being rendered the prop "attractions" will be undefined so you need to achieve this with the condition to make the error go away.

```
{attractions && this.renderMapMarker()}
```

Comment: erro : Can't find variable:attractions

Comment: As I said you are trying to access the variable that is not available in the props yet. You are using object destructuring to read the var "attractions" from props.  try this 

`attractions = this.props.attractions` and then check the variable for null before renderMapMarker

Answer (score 0):

Just add ? after attractions and it should work.

renderMapMarker = () => {
const {attractions} = this.props;

```
  return attractions?.map(marker => {
    return (
      <Marker
        key={marker.caseId}
        title={marker.caseName}
        description="點擊查看詳細資料"
        coordinate={{
          latitude: marker.latitude,
          longitude: marker.longitude,
        }}
      />
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this run ok....